# Populating Datagrid with Data from Multiple Tables

Tags: c#, sql, .net, datagrid

I need to populate a datagrid with the following columns.

invnumber,itemname,rate,quantity..

itemname,rate,quantity comes from 1 table while invnumber comes from another table

I used to do like this

```
 string commandText = "SELECT invnumber,cname,date FROM inv_table WHERE invnumber LIKE @id";
                            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn);
                            string searchParam = String.Format("%{0}%", text_inv.Text);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", searchParam);


                            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                            {
                                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                                {
                                    sda.Fill(dt);
                                    dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
                                }
                            }
```

Now i cannot directly assign the data source as 2 different tables are involved

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
```

How can i get around this.

Comment: Why don't you join these tables?

Comment: @un-lucky.. can you post an example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To emit combined result from 2 or more different tables in a table, use either `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN` or `UNION` statement depending on your need.

In this case, you need to join first table and other table to get desired results, assume invnumber is unique or primary key. Here is an example:

```
string commandText = "SELECT other.invnumber, inv.cname, inv.date FROM inv_table AS inv 
INNER JOIN other_table AS other 
ON inv.invnumber = other.invnumber 
WHERE other.invnumber LIKE @id";
```

Or if you have already defined classes for each table, use LINQ to SQL with lambda expression:

```
DataContext dc = new DataContext();
var results = dc.InvTable.Join(OtherTable, inv => inv.invnumber, other => other.invnumber, (inv, other) => new { invnumber = other.invnumber, cname = inv.cname, date = inv.date });
```

Any improvements and suggestions welcome.

Comment: Since I don't know what field on your `inv_table` designed as foreign key, I assume you have `invnumber` in your `inv_table` as foreign key to `other_table`'s primary key when dealing with ON equality statement inside INNER JOIN. Please define foreign key for `inv_table` point to `other_table` if exists.

Comment: I have defined id as the the primary key for both tables.

Comment: Thus you need to change ON clause as `ON inv.id = other.id` if you have same id record for both tables. If you have other field on `inv_table` rather than primary key as foreign key, change ON clause to `inv.foreignid = other.id`, where `foreignid` stands for all same ids on `other_table`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class for the data structure of the 2 different table, populate the new one and use. (easier and the most clear solution)